# Sum with filter criteria Excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to use a formula with setting filter in a column. I have some columns in a sheet like this:

Column A: 10, 20, 30, 40, 47, KK, AA, Z8

Column AA : 123.443.222, 322.333.233, etc (this column has blanks in between)

In another cell I have this formula:

```
 =SUM(IF(LEN(AA2:AA24000)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(AA2:24000,".",""))>0,1,0))
```

This gives me the count of total items present in column AA.

I want to use the same formula combined with the filter from column A. That means if column A contains "10","20","30","40", then give me the count of items in column AA.

I thank in advance for your help.

Comment: Why don't you use `COUNTA(AA:AA)` to get the number of items in `AA`? as for your question, I`m not sure I understand what the result you want is, but `COUNTIF` maybe?

Comment: I tried using "COUNTA", but not able to get the count. Maybe because of the empty cells in the column. I need the count of items present in the column AA with the criteria in column A.

Comment: Try [`COUNTIF`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34)

Comment: I tried COUNTIF as well, it didn't work.

Comment: in office356 there IS a FILTER() function, worth considering. u can make SUM(FILTER(...)) from it. ( :